# Why couldn't my gulp work

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

This is my `gulpfiles.js`:

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
let browserify = require('browserify');
let babelify = require('babelify');
let source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
let buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');


    gulp.task('js',()=>{
        browserify({
            entries : ['App/app.js'],
            extensive : ['.js'],
            debug:true
        })
            .transform(babelify,babelify.configure())
            .bundle()
            .pipe(source('app.js'))
            .pipe(buffer())
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
    });

    gulp.task('default',['js']);
```

And this is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015","react","stage-1"]
}
```

This is my `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>Weather-App</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
<script src="build/app.js"></script>
</html>
```

This is my `./App/app.js`:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'

    class Helloworld extends React.Purecomponent{
        render(){
            return(
                <h1> Good morning </h1>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDom.render(
            <Helloworld />,
            document.getElementById('app')
    );
```

I don't know how it could be that when I start my browser, it displays nothing. It displays no error during the packing process.

Answer (score 1):

To view browserify errors, you need to subscribe to the `error` event. Try something like:

```
gulp.task('js',()=>{
    browserify({
        entries : ['App/app.js'],
        extensive : ['.js'],
        debug:true
    })
        .transform(babelify,babelify.configure())
        .bundle()
        .on('error', function (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
          this.emit('end');
        })
        .pipe(source('app.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('build'))
});

gulp.task('default',['js']);
```

Specifically for your case, there are a few errors with your component. It should be `PureComponent` instead of `Purecomponent` and `ReactDOM` instead of `ReactDom`:

```
class Helloworld extends React.PureComponent{
  render(){
    return(
      <h1> Good morning </h1>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Helloworld />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I use PureComponent instead of Purecomponent and it workded

Comment: @answerhua no problem. As I mentioned, I encourage you to subscribe to the error event. It will make development a lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

It works when i change React.Purecomponent to React.Component.

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'

    class Helloworld extends React.Component{
        render(){
            return(
                <h1> Good morning </h1>
            );
        }
    }

    ReactDom.render(
            <Helloworld />,
            document.getElementById('app')
    );
```